# Can interlock or registrator be still helpful after docker engine 1.12.3 in swarm mode?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-engine

docker engine 1.12.3 in swarm mode comes with the ingress LB with the help of  routing mesh which redirects to only the task which is healthy .

Just wondering if interlock(https://github.com/ehazlett/interlock) & registrator (https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator) be still useful to ensure request goes to the healthy container ?

I got confused due to "deploy-infra" (Reputation didn't allowed me to use more than 2 links ) article on docs.docker.com .

Answer (score 0):

Registrator is not useful in Docker Swarm Mode.

You can install it on every node, and it will listen the evens. Registrator will also catch the container creation of the service task container. However, since ports are not published, Registrator will ignore the event and send nothing to Consul (or wherever it sends the data).